# Cannot use siglen parameter while creating index gist_trgm_ops in PostgreSQL 11.19 (Azure flexible DB)

Tags: postgresql, azure, postgresql-11, azure-postgresql, gist-index

When trying to create index on remote Azure server *(PostgreSQL 11.19 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit)* `create index test on "Table" using gist("Name" gist_trgm_ops(siglen=256));` with custom siglen parameter I see syntax error in console

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
> LINE 2: using gist("VariationName" gist_trgm_ops(siglen=256));
> ^
>
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 92

But if I try to execute this code on my local machine with local server *(PostgreSQL 15.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit)* there is no error.

What version of PostgreSQL supports siglen in indexes or what setting I can change in Azure to resolve this issue?

I tried to change some sttings on Azure flixible server side but didn't succeeded with that.

Comment: You are right. That's about TRGM extension https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. You need to use PostgreSQL 13+ in order to create **gist_trgm_ops** indexes with custom siglen parameter.